# preceding xpath axes giving improper results

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

Consider following html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="Animal" align="center">
            <h2>Animal</h2>
            <div class="Vertebrate" align="left" >
                <h3 align="left">Vertebrate</h3>
                <div class="Fish">
                    <h4 >Fish</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="Mammal">
                    <h4>Mammal</h4>
                    <div class="Herbivore">
                        <h5>Herbivore</h5>
                    </div>
                    <div class="Carnivore">
                        <h5>Carnivore</h5>
                        <div class="Lion">
                            <h6>Lion</h6>
                        </div>
                        <div class="Tiger">
                            <h6>Tiger</h6>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="Other">
                    <h4>Other</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="Invertebrate">
                <h3>Invertebrate</h3>
                <div class="Insect">
                    <h4>Insect</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="Crustacean">
                    <h4>Crustacean</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

What is the difference between:

```
//div[@class='Mammal']//preceding::div
```

and

```
//div[@class='Mammal']/preceding::div
```

Note the **double slash** within xpath in first and **single slash** in second.

`//div[@class='Mammal']//preceding::div` gives one result while `//div[@class='Mammal']/preceding::div` gives 5 results in chrome version 86.

In my view

`//div[@class='Mammal']//preceding::div` should give 3 results:

```
<div class="Animal">
<div class="Vertebrate">
<div class="Fish">
```

why it is not giving so?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference between these two expressions:

#### Expression 1

```
//div[@class='Mammal']/preceding::div
```

selects any preceding `<div>` seen directly from `<div class="Mammal">`.

Because elements must be closed in order to be considered `prededing`, the only `<div>` where that is true in your example HTML is

```
<div class="Fish">
```

#### Expression 2

```
//div[@class='Mammal']//preceding::div
```

selects any preceding `<div>` seen from any descendant of `<div class="Mammal">`.

In your example HTML this applies to

```
<div class="Fish">
<div class="Herbivore">
<div class="Carnivore">
<div class="Lion">
<div class="Tiger">
```

The `Tiger` is preceding a text node descendant from `Mammal`, so it's part of the result.

#### Your Expectation

> should give 3 results:
>
> ```
> <div class="Animal">
> <div class="Vertebrate">
> <div class="Fish">
> ```

One of those is satisfied by your Expression 1. The other two are `ancestor`, not `preceding`.

So this would work (in XPath 1.0):

```
//div[@class='Mammal']/preceding::div|//div[@class='Mammal']/ancestor::div
```

or, shorter (in XPath 2.0)

```
//div[@class='Mammal']/(preceding::div|ancestor::div)
```

Comment: Why does it return `<div class="Tiger">`? Which node that is the descendant of `<div class="Mammal">` does it precede?

Comment: @AlexeyR. Added the explanation why the Tiger is selected to the answer.

Comment: Isn't that `div` an ancestor of that text node hence should not be selected?

Comment: @AlexeyR. No, it's preceding that text node. Outlined by `[]`: `<div class="Tiger">[ ]<h6>Tiger</h6>[ ]</div>[ *this one* ]</div>`.

Comment: Note that despite of `xpath-2.0` tag OP also specified `selenium`. Selenium doesn't support XPath2.0, so your *shorter* version will lead to `SyntaxError`... and, by the way, your other solution is just an inverted version of mine :)

Comment: In expression it is mentioned that //div[@class='Mammal'] then why it is seeing preceding div from ANY DESCENDANT of div with class mammal? Is not that it should see preceding from context node div[@class='Mammal']

Comment: @aLearner Not when you use `//`.

Comment: @JaSON True about the XPath 2.0, I've added that as a hint. And yeah, there are many ways to solve a task in XPath, so all expressions that return the same results are variants of each other.

Comment: regarding my comment that why it is taking descendants of div[@class='Mammal']  also one can check https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-31/#abbrev

Comment: @Tomalak Can u please explain to whom `<div class="Carnivore">` and `<div class="Tiger">` is preceding? I still could not understand how `<div class="Tiger">` is preceding text node `<h6>Tiger</h6>`? It is the parent of it and parents are not included in preceding?

Comment: @aLearner https://our.umbraco.com/documentation/reference/templating/macros/xslt/xpath-axes-and-their-shortcuts (Perspective: This question is *one year* old and you're asking me to explain basic things for you that you could have found yourself out in that time. One year is a lot of time for reading.)

Answer (score 0):

Your expectation to get this result

```
<div class="Animal">
<div class="Vertebrate">
<div class="Fish">
```

is not correct as only `class="Fish"` is *preceding* node while two other are *ancestors*. If you want to get this result try

```
//div[following::div[@class='Mammal'] or descendant::div[@class='Mammal']]
```